# Get value from "IO a" is interpreted as list

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell with [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Solutions/Higher-order_functions_and_Currying).

Given is the signature. The solution to the problem is:

```
sequenceIO :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequenceIO [] = return []
sequenceIO (a:as) = do {v <-a ; vs <- (sequenceIO as) ; return (v : vs)}
```

My solution was (which does not work):

```
sequenceIO xs = return (foldl get [] xs)
  where get ys act = do y <- act
                        ys ++ [y]
```

The "get" singled out as a function:

```
gett :: [a] -> IO a -> [a]
gett ys act = do y <- act
                 ys ++ y
```

will not work: a list as a second parameter is infered. Why? In the solution the `v <-a` works too.

Comment: Because you return a list, the compiler infers that you are in the list monad, which makes `act` a list.

Comment: Your `get` and `gett` functions are not the same, the last lines `ys ++ y` and `ys ++ [y]` are different. However you can't implement your `gett` function since you need to propagate `IO`. It should have type `[a] -> IO a -> IO [a]` instead.

Comment: @Lee: Thanks. The first part you mention was a mistake as it should have been the same as in the where-block of sequenceIO. I think, my understanding is just not enough yet, but why do I need to propagate `IO`?

Comment: @Lee: I think, in Paul's answer my comment-question is being discussed ("Once you are in the IO Monad, you will always be."). Nevertheless, I don't understand why. If you have a simple answer, that would be great, but otherwise, I think, I just have to study a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your solution doesn't work is that you cannot simply escape the IO Monad. Once you are in the IO Monad, you will always be. This is actually one of the really great things about Haskell, because you can't hide side effects and can tell by a functions type signature what type of effects it is allowed to do.

The type signature of your `gett` function should actually be

```
gett :: [a] -> IO a -> IO [a]
```

However you're function will still not typecheck:

1) A small oversight: `ys ++ y` should actually be `ys ++ [y]` (as it was for `get` in the `where` clause) because append (`++`) works on lists.

2) `ys ++ [y]` would still have the wrong type. It must be of type `IO [a]` but is of type `[a]`. You can get it into `IO [a]` by doing `return $ ys ++ [y]`. Here `return` has type `return :: a -> IO a`, it *lifts* any value into the monad.

`gett` is then:

```
gett :: [a] -> IO a -> IO [a]
gett ys act = do
  y <- act
  return $ ys ++ [y]
```

We're now getting close, but we're not quite there yet. Now the problem is with `foldl get [] xs`: `foldl` works on plain lists, not on lists inside monads. However, we can use `foldM` from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) and write `sequenceIO` as follows:

```
sequenceIO :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequenceIO xs = foldM gett [] xs
```

which should typecheck and work.

Full program:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)  -- this only imports foldM from Control.Monad

gett :: [a] -> IO a -> IO [a]
gett ys act = do
  y <- act
  return $ ys ++ [y]

sequenceIO :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequenceIO xs = foldM gett [] xs
```

Now a good exercise is to figure out how `foldM` works ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, regarding “Once you are in the IO Monad, you will always be”, there *is* `unsafePerformIO`, but that ought not be used unless one knows *exactly* what it does and is absolutely sure that it does not do anything bad in one's use case – since it usually does. I for one use it for debugging sometimes, to slip in a `seq (unsafePerformIO (putStrLn (show …)))` at convenient locations to print intermediate values.

Comment: @ManuelEberl why not use `Debug.Trace`?

Comment: Because I did not know it previously and never previously required sophisticated debugging in Haskell, so I never looked it up. However, it turns out `Debug.Trace` uses `unsafePerformIO` internally as well, so it's basically the same as what I did anyway.

Comment: Point 1) was a stupid mistake since it was supposed to be the same as in the "where"-block from the sequenceIO function.

Comment: @ManuelEberl you are of course right about `unsafePerformIO`, but as you say it is an escape hatch that you need to wrap FFI functions or for real advanced hackery (observable sharing and such). Given the level of the question I thought it best to ignore these details for now, he'll come across them soon enough...

Comment: @tobias.h yeah, you actually had that in the `where` clause (must admit I overlooked it when writing the answer). I didn't mean to dwell on it, I just wanted to give a step by step solution.

Comment: Folding a list using a function which does `ys ++ [y]` has quadratic complexity I think, I believe it would be more efficient to rather do `y : ys` instead and then [`reverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:reverse) at the end.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yes it does, `ys ++ [y]` is really a red flag, but I think the focus of the question was on getting the types to work. Maybe a comment would have been in order though ...

Comment: @Paul: that's ok this way. the answer is better complete than not.